# Java type captures for wildcards in collections

Tags: java, generics, collections, types

I would like to do this (minimal repro):

```
String key = "foo";
Object value = new Bar();

if (target instanceof Map<?,?>) {
    Map<?,?> map = (Map<?,?>)target;
    map.put(key, value);
    ...
```

But I am told this:

> The method put(capture#25-of ?, capture#26-of ?) in the type
>   Map is not applicable for the
>   arguments (String, Object)

It seems like String and Object should both be okay here.  My question has two parts: (1) why? And (2) how can I make something like this work?

Comment: java generics inheritance is little different than class inheritance. You need to explicitly associate the inheritance by setting bounds. You need to say something like ? extends Object to make it work.http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html

Comment: Not related to the problem, but the `(Object)` cast is entirely redundant...

Comment: Yes, yes, please ignore the cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that collections that use unbounded wildcards don't allow elements to be added to them. If they did, you could cast the collection to have more specific type parameters, and all of a sudden the type-safety that generics are supposed to offer is gone:

```
Map<?,?> map = (Map<?,?>)target;
map.put(key, value);  // Not actually allowed
Map<String, String> evilMap = (Map<String, String>)map;
String barAsString = evilMap.get(key); // But it's actually a Bar!
```

Comment: So, is it the case that if I have a map but don't know what the parameterized types are I cannot add to it?  I guess I need to use reflection to get the parameterized types... ?

Comment: @jeffamaphone Well, you can always use the raw type if you "know". I would try to refactor so that I always knew what type of map I was adding to (if possible.)

Comment: The question is, how come you don't know the type of the data in the Map. If you don't know what it contains, how can you be sure you will not be corrupting it by adding incorrect data?

Comment: @jeffamaphone From the JLS, under [Raw Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8): The use of raw types is allowed only as a concession to compatibility of legacy code. The use of raw types in code written after the introduction of generics into the Java programming language is strongly discouraged. It is possible that future versions of the Java programming language will disallow the use of raw types.

Comment: Well, I know the key is a String and I know the value is an Object.  But when I try `Map<String, Object>` I get: `Cannot perform instanceof check against parameterized type Map<String,Object>. Use the form Map<?,?> instead since further generic type information will be erased at runtime`.

Comment: What I don't know is if I have a map and I need to set a value for the key, or if I have an Object and I need to call a setter for the field named `key` and pass `value` as the new value.

Comment: The `instanceof` operator acts on classes, since generics works with type erasure, at runtime, there is only one class for all generic types. As such, you do not do `x instance of Map<?,?>` because there is not a class for `Map<?,?>`, the only class that exists is the type erasure of `|Map<?,?>|` which is simply `Map`. Thus, you must do: `x instance of Map`. That's all you can ask about your generic types, because the runtime type system does not know anything about the generic types in question. Isn't it the way it should work?

Comment: That makes sense, Edwin.  Is there a way to avoid the resulting unchecked cast warning then?

Comment: You cannot avoid the warning because evidently you're running a risk here, but if you really think you know more than the compiler in this case by forcing the cast, then you can prevent the warning from being generated by adding a annotation `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` on the casting expression or in the method that contains it.

Comment: I do know more than the compiler.  This seems unsafe and ridiculous, I know, but I'm trying to copy Key Value coding features of NSDictionary and NSObject for an expression parser that operates on a very tightly scoped but untyped language. Since Objective-C doesn't seem to care about types that much, its easier to get away with.

Comment: And the reason I know more than the compiler is because the compiler threw away the shit it knew.

Answer (score 1):

Map<?, ?> really means, Map<? extends Object, ? extends Object> According to Java typesystem, you can only get values of type parameters specialized with ? extends wildcard from method calls. You can't pass it to the methods.

P.S. Probably you want Map<Object, Object>

Comment: Yes, I really want `Map<String, Object>` but I can't check that as a type for `target`: `Cannot perform instanceof check against parameterized type Map<String,Object>. Use the form Map<?,?> instead since further generic type information will be erased at runtime`

Comment: It's impossible to check in Java since it uses type erasure implementation of generics.

Answer (score 0):

[This blog post](http://blog.codeaholics.org/2011/generics-and-the-mystical-wildcard/) provides the answer. In short, the compiler doesn't know if `Map<?, ?>` is really a `Map<String, Object>` or, say, a `Map<Integer, Double>`, so it can't guarantee type safety for you.